# What is the meaning of the phrase "to paraphrase half a dozen"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> What do you mean by saying that " the value of a string literal is not known until runtime"?
>
> I am **paraphrasing half a dozen** other comments posted across various answers.

What does the phrase "to paraphrase half a dozen" mean?

Comment: I am paraphrasing comments. The comments I'm paraphrasing are half a dozen other comments posted across various answers.

Comment: half a dozen = 6 -> I am paraphrasing 6 comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are splitting the sentence in the wrong place.

I am **paraphrasing half a dozen other comments** posted across various answers.

I am paraphrasing [something]. What is that something? Half a dozen other comments.

"Half a dozen" can mean "exactly six" or "approximately six".